Why is Dilatation subgroup $SO(1,1)$?
Why is dilatation subgroup of the conformal group $SO(1,1)$? I am not sure if this is a result for 2D theories or even higher dimensional ones too. (Parameter counting suggests there is one parameter which is indeed everything that is required for arbitrary dimensions). I didn't encounter this in a CFT text but in the AdS/CFT book by Martin and Erdmenger where the (Euclidean) AdS Poincare patch has the metric $$ds^2=\frac{dz^2+dt^2+d\vec{x}^2}{z^2}$$ and the text says that there is a manifest scale invariance via the isometry $(z,t,x) \to \lambda(z, t, x)$ whereas on the CFT side it is a scale transformation of the metric, specifically a dilatation. In other words a Killing vector on the bulk side became a Conformal Killing vector on the boundary side. Neat. But what if I don't want to use AdS/CFT. How to see that $SO(1,1)$ corresponds to a dilatation transformation?

Well, dilatations/scaling $SO^+(1,1)\cong\mathbb{R}_+$ constitute a non-compact 1-dimensional group.

How to see this and how do we show that indeed $\mathbb{R}$ is the group of dilatations (modulo $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factors)?
